# Importing a code-containing __init__.py from a cousin folder?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, package, relative-path

Given the directory structure:

```
program/
      setup.py                                      
      ilm/                  
              __init__.py
              app/
                      __init__.py
      bin/                  
              script.py
```

**Note: the setup.py is not a typical setup.py, rather it is a custom-made setup uniquely for py2app.**

`program/ilm/app/__init__.py` is non-empty: it contains a `main()` function, which instantiates a class in the same file. My question: In `program/ilm/bin/script.py`, if I want to import and execute the `main()` function in `program/ilm/app/__init__.py`, what are the valid ways of achieving this? The reason I ask is that *script.py* is doing so thus:

```
import ilm.app as app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.main()
```

Based on my (admittedly limited) understanding of packaging and importing, this *shouldn't* work, since we have not explicitly told script.py where to look for `project/ilm/app/__init__.py` using `..`. And indeed, I get:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Pyderman:program Pyderman$ python ./bin/script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/script.py", line 5, in <module>
    import ilm.app as app
ImportError: No module named ilm.app
```

**In contrast, when the Python interpreter is started in /project, `import ilm.app as app` works fine.**

This is apparently fully-functional production code which I should not have to change to get running.

1. Is the `import` statement valid, given the directory structure, and if so, what am I missing?
2. If not, what is the recommended way of getting the import to work? Add the path using `sys.path.append()` above the `import` statement? Or use `..` notation in the `import` statement to explicitly point to program to pick up `project/ilm/app/__init__.py`? Is the fact that it is an `__init__.py` I am trying to import significant?

Comment: Python version:  2.7.10

Comment: Have you actually *installed* `iml`? Is its directory on your path? Is there a `setup.py` anywhere?

Comment: iml is a directory in the package (see folder structure above)

Comment: That doesn't address any of my questions... Have a read through e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: iml isn't a third-party module. It's part of the developed code-base (of this project).

Comment: Probably you need to add the top level directory to your `sys.path` variable before the import statement.

Comment: @Pyderman ...yes, I understand that. How is that relevant to *any* of what I've told you? Please take the time to actually read the link I've provided.

Comment: @jonrsharpe answers: 1) I've installed nothing (just cloned in Git) 2) I've tried adding the path to /ilm to sys.path before the import statement; makes no difference. 3) Nope

Comment: Unless you can give a [mcve], there's no point discussing this further.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Fair point well made.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Have re-written the question here, perhaps this clarifies things a little http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770853/importing-a-code-containing-init-py-from-a-cousin-folder

Comment: Why didn't you edit this?

Comment: @jonrsharpe a clean slate is all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so with my re-write closed as a duplicate, and with no new comments or answers in this original (although rewritten also), is this an outcome that is of benefit to anyone?

Comment: Who benefits from you opening the same question again? It's more moderation work, for a start. You seem to have had several answers, only one of which you've deigned to comment on; why not interact more here? And it's only been a few hours, you should have some patience and remember that if you want support on demand you should pay someone for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things. You need to make sure the iml directory is in the python path. Either make sure you are running python from the right directory or add the right path to sys.path list. And you need to make sure that both iml and app directory both have

```
__init__.py
```

file, since python needs to interpret the whole thing as a hierarchy of modules rather than just dirs. Then you should be able to do

```
from iml import app
```

Answer (score 1):

The obvious conclusion would seem to be that the `iml` directory has an `__init__.py` inside it, but why that would happen in your production setup is hard to say. Have you checked in the production environment whether this is the case?

Assuming that the production environment *is* importing the package at `iml/app` (which you can check by examining `app.__file__`) then the program will indeed execute the `main` function from the `__init__.py` file - but `__init__.py` might easily be importing it from sonewhere else rather than defining it locally.

Comment: Yes there is indeed an `__init__.py` within the iml folder (above the app folder). It's empty apart from a docstring, if that has any significance.

Comment: Nope, even an empty `__init__.py` is enough to identify the directory as a package. But since the `iml` directory is not in the same directory as your program, the directory containing it must be added to `sys.path`, which I suspect you will find is hte case for your production environment.

Answer (score 0):

The Python package needs proper `setup.py` [which defines the package structure](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing/). Furthermore `bin/` scripts should be defined as [console_scripts entry points](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing/#console-scripts).

[This all must be installed in a proper Python environment, not just any folder](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing/).

Comment: `setup.py` is for installation, and does not affect a statically installed directory. It isn't consulted on import.